# Does physical exercise of a specific part affect muscles in the other parts of the body?

Tags: endocrinology, muscles

There is a theory among bodybuilders, that is, if you train big muscle groups (e.g. legs, chest), it will increase the overall growth of muscles all over the body; the trained muscle will release signals (what are they?) into the blood stream and in turn, triggers the release of muscle growth/repair hormones (insulin-like growth factor?) which have effects on any (skeleton) muscle cells.

- Is this story true?
- Will the muscle growth/repair hormones also enhance the smooth muscle or cardiac muscle?

Comment: Definitely a question that should be asked on [bodybuilding.SE](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bodybuilding).

Comment: @Remi.b, the OP is interested in knowing if the popular notion amongst bodybuilders has some authentic biological basis.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I would assume that on bodybuilding.SE they care about verifying their claims.

Comment: @Remi.b thank you for the link. But I just want to find out whether these popular claims are supported by rigorous study. I looked at some references cited by bodybuilding experts, they are pretty crappy.

Comment: http://jap.physiology.org/content/65/6/2406 here is a paper on training and increase in testosterone.

Comment: @ChenChao what were the references by the bodybuilding experts?